# Parsing XML on multiple levels on React Native using React-Native-RSS-Parse

Tags: xml, react-native, rss

I am parsing an XML and extracting information from there. Some items will be returned correctly but other will return “undefined”.

This is the demo I’m working on.

https://snack.expo.io/@leourushi/api-looping-01-threecalls

This is the original XML I’m pulling data from:
https://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/metro_service_status/feeds/mis/rail.xml
And I used this tool to parse XML into readable format:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rss-parser

If I return

```
item.title
```

or

```
item.description
```

it will return information as expected.
However, if I try to return

```
<source>
```

or

```
<pubDate>
```

, it will only return ‘undefined’.

The way XML is presented makes it look as if those two elements are sub categories within , much like arrays work. So I tried both of the formats below:

```
item.source
item.description.source
```

But both will return the same result.

Right now, I’m only using alert() function to see if it extracts the information I’m expecting from the XML.

Why are these categories behaving differently? Is there a way to retrieve these elements from XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at "Model mappings" in readme file. There are fields which supported by library and their mappings. Key "pubDate" can be accessed by item.published, key "source" is not supported in spec. You can execute

```
alert(Object.keys(item));
```

to see what keys does item contain and then log values if necessary

Comment: Oh that's what that section means! Thanks! I can confirm item.published returns the info as expected. Thanks! I will mark this as solved.